# Transforming Doobie ConnectionIO[Option[Int]] without explicit match

Tags: scala, free-monad, doobie

I have a `ConnectionIO[Option[Int]]` and map over the `Option` to  produce a `ConnectionIO[Option[String]]` with a query the `Some[Int]` otherwise keep the `Nones. I was able to do this with a`for`comprehension and a`match`:

```
def findWidgetByOwner(name: String): ConnectionIO[Option[String]] = for {
    opt <- sql"SELECT owner_id FROM owners WHERE name = $name".query[Int].option
    widget <- opt match {
        case None => None.pure[ConnectionIO]
        case Some(id) => sql"SELECT widget_name FROM widgets WHERE owner_id = $id".query[String].option
    }
} yield widget
```

I know i'm getting tripped up by the `ConnectionIO` container, but I can't find a cleaner mapping approach that to transform `ConnectionIO[Option[Int]]` to `ConnectionIO[Option[String]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be cleaner to join using SQL instead of scala:

```
def findWidgetByOwner(name: String): ConnectionIO[Option[String]] = 
  sql"""
    SELECT widgets.widget_name FROM widgets WHERE owner_id = $id
    INNER JOIN owners ON widgets.owner_id = owners.owner_id
    WHERE owners.name = $name
  """.query[Int].option
```

But if you want to clean up the original, some incantation of `sequence` would probably work (not tested):

```
import cats._, cats.data._, cats.implicits._

...
widget <- opt.map {id => 
  sql"SELECT widget_name FROM widgets WHERE owner_id = $id".query[String].unique
}.sequence
```

***Note:*** You have to change `query[String].option` to `.query[String].unique` otherwise `widget` becomes an `Option[Option[String]]` which if the widget query can be null, might be desirable, but requires a `.flatten` at the end.

Comment: Yes, ideally these things are solved in SQL, but the question was just using the SQL was purely for illustration of the composition problem